# How can I overfit a fully-connected neural network to predict RGB values from (x,y) coordinates?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, multiple-regression, overfitting, keras

The problem is the following:
Given a single 3-channel image (e.g. 200x150), I constructed a dataset where the features are the pairs of **(x,y)** coordinates and the targets are the **(R,G,B)** values. Each {(x,y) , (r,g,b)} is a training example. The aim is to overfit the training set (another way to see this is to be able to reconstruct the image pixel by pixel).

I would like to achieve an almost perfect reconstruction, but even with

- a neural network with `4 hidden layers`
- ReLU activation function in each layer, except the output layer
- `1.000.000 parameters`
- normalizing features and targets between [0,1]
- training `300 epochs` with `rmsprop`
- weights from a normal with mean 0 and std 0.05 and the biases at 0.

I can only achieve `0.005 mean squared error` (normalized). 
How can I improve this performance? Do I need better preprocessing, network architecture, ecc, ...?

**summary:** The network is pretty useless, bu you can interpret the question this way:
How can I overfit a dataset with `200x150=30k` training examples, each with 2 features (x,y) and 3 targets (r,g,b), With `range(x) = [0,Width)`, `range(y) = [0, Height)` and `range r,g,b = [0,255]`, using a fully-connected neural network?

Comment: Your input is 8x3xWxH and you want to reconstruct this from just WxH, is this your goal?

Comment: No, the input is one pair of (x,y) and the output is one triple of (r,g,b). So the input layer has 2 inputs and the output layer has 3 outputs. The image itself forms the dataset.

Comment: How many images are in the training data set?

Comment: Just one. I edited the question to clarify. The dataset has thus 200x150 training examples. I just want to overfit that image.

Comment: You are trying to reconstruct an image ... from *itself*??  With 90,001 parameters you can store it perfectly!

Comment: The information content of your image is only 200x150x3 Bytes=90,000 Bytes, which means that in the worst case you should need no more than 90K/2 = 45,000 single precision floating point parameters

Comment: What's the goal of this network? It sounds pretty useless

Comment: It seems interesting enough from the perspective of testing the capacity of a network / how capable SGD is of making use of that capacity.

Comment: @DeltaIV The network is useless indeed. You can interpret the question as follows:

How can I overfit a dataset with  200x150=30k training examples, each with 2 features (x,y) and 3 targets (r,g,b)? With range(x) = [0,Width), range(y) = [0, Height) and range r,g,b = [0,255]

Comment: You want a map $(x,y) \rightarrow (r,g,b)$. Isn't that what the picture itself is?

Comment: @oneloop You can forget that we are talking about an image. The underlying aim is to overfit a training set with 30k examples with (x,y) as features, and 3 (r,g,b) targets. This can be translated in being able to reconstruct the image, pixel by pixel, given its coordinates, but it is not the principal goal.

Comment: @ThanksBye Done. Does my response answer it? It's exactly what you asked, although it's completely pointless :-)

Comment: @shimao not really. [It would have been interesting to see how a real deep neural network memorizes a real data set](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.03530) and it's already been done, though some of the conclusions of that paper are wrong. Here we don't need a deep neural network at all (linear neural networks are never deep, or to be pedantic they don't gain any approximation power at all by becoming deep).

Comment: By the way, I was able to push the error down to 0.002 MSE using a similar architecture as OP by decaying the learning rate a factor of 10 every 200 epochs from 1E-3 to 1E-7. Although it's not close to being perfect yet.

Comment: @shimao that's great, I didn't even try to train for more than 300 epochs because it is so boring. Do you have an example image to see how it looks like with 0.002 error?

Comment: This is a 256x256 image -- so about twice the size as your image. I took it from the wikipedia page on test images. [ground truth](https://i.imgur.com/1lUwtP8.png) and [prediction](https://i.imgur.com/Oez4IAg.png). I used 8 hidden layers of 512 units and selu activation.

Answer (score 2):

The [SIREN paper](https://vsitzmann.github.io/siren/) ("Implicit Neural Representations with Periodic Activation Functions" --  *NeurIPS 2020*) earlier this year shows that ReLU networks are pretty bad at that task.

Instead, they propose to use the sine as activation function and show improved performance in a variety of tasks.

So, perhaps try exchanging ReLU for sine, that might solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have 30k $(x_i,y_i)$ inputs and 30k $(r_i,g_i,b_i)$ targets. $i$ goes from 1 to 30k.

Consider the following network. For each $((x,y), (r,g,b))$ pair you have 3 "linear neurons", each with 2 weights:

$r = \omega_{r,x} x + \omega_{r,y} y$

$g = \omega_{g,x} x + \omega_{g,y} y$

$b = \omega_{b,x} x + \omega_{b,y} y$

The complete set of neurons:

$r_i = \omega_{i,r,x} x + \omega_{i,r,y} y$

$g_i = \omega_{i,g,x} x + \omega_{i,g,y} y$

$b_i = \omega_{i,b,x} x + \omega_{i,b,y} y$

That's a total of 30k * 2 * 3 = 180k weights $\omega$. This will fit exactly.

EDIT: Each of those three systems has 3 equatins and 6 parameters, so they're underdetermined. An alternative which is exactly determined would be:

$r_i = \omega_{i,r} x + y$

$g_i = \omega_{i,g} x + y$

$b_i = \omega_{i,b} x + y$

This "neural network" now has $90k$ weights.

Comment: This is not exactly what I am trying to do. My network would have 2 input neurons (a single pixel coordinate (x_i, y_i) ) and 3 output neurons (the RGB values for that pixel).

Comment: You asked to overfit. With 2 neurons you can't overfit 30k parameters.

Comment: Also your OWN example says that you tried 4 hidden layers, and 1M parameters, so you're not trying just 2 neurons.

Comment: Right, in the comment above I just clarified the input and output dimensions (because it looked like you understood I was using 30k inputs and 30 outputs). So, I use 2 inputs neurons, 3 output neurons and 4 hidden layers with, say 500 neurons each. 
I also tried with 5 hidden layers, or with 1000 neurons per layer, without improvements w.r.t the 3-500-500-500-500-2 architecture. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: @ThanksBye Ok, in that case I pose the following question to you: what makes you think that specific architecture will allow overfitting this specific problem? I mean, it might or might not, but can you prove either way?

Comment: In fact I asked how I can improve that. Surely there are better preprocessing techniques, weight initializations, activation function to use (I didn't mention I use ReLU, I will edit), or architectures. I am looking for hints in this direction.

Comment: I'm curious: what are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: Nothing in particular, it is just an exercise to learn. But if you like you can see it as an image compressor. If the network's size is less than the compressed image size it could be convenient, but I doubt that can be achieved.

Comment: @ThanksBye There's plenty of books on compression. Reading one would be more productive than throwing neural networks at the problem and hope it solves itself. Also most modern image file types already have compression built-in.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been solved for the 3D case by NeRFs. The problem is that the network cannot easily tell the difference between position (0,0) and (0,1) - it doesn't have the input resolution to distinguish them.

To solve this, you need to spread the information across more inputs using a positional encoding - see ["Fourier Features Let Networks Learn High Frequency Functions in Low Dimensional Domains"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.10739) where they address your exact scenario.

More info: https://bmild.github.io/fourfeat/index.html